# "Use of networking APIs requires the ID_CAP_NETWORKING capability to be defined in the application manifest."

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am writing a **Windows Phone 8.1 (WINRT) app**.

I am using **WebAuthenticationBroker** to login via google+

```
 public async void ContinueWebAuthentication(WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs args)
        {
            WebAuthenticationResult result = args.WebAuthenticationResult;

            switch (result.ResponseStatus)
            {
                case WebAuthenticationStatus.Success:
                    {  
                        var response = result.ResponseData;                        
                        string responseString = result.ResponseData.ToString();
                        _authorizationCode = responseString.Substring(response.IndexOf("=") + 1);                        

                        await getAccessToken();
                        break;
                    }
                case WebAuthenticationStatus.UserCancel:
                    {

                        break;
                    }
                default:
                case WebAuthenticationStatus.ErrorHttp:
                    {               
                    break;

                    }

            }

        }


         private async Task getAccessToken()
        {

            string oauthUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";

            HttpClient theAuthClient = new HttpClient();

              HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, oauthUrl);

                 // default case, we have an authentication code, want a refresh/access token            
                 string content = "code=" + _authorizationCode + "&" +
                     "client_id=" + singletonInstance.GoogleClientID + "&" +
                     "client_secret=" + singletonInstance.GoogleClientSecret + "&" +
                     "redirect_uri=" + singletonInstance.GoogleCallbackUrl + "&" +
                     "grant_type=authorization_code";

                 request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;

                 request.Content = new StreamContent(new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content)));
                 request.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                 try
                 {
                     HttpResponseMessage response = await theAuthClient.SendAsync(request);
                     parseAccessToken(response);
                 }
                 catch (HttpRequestException)
                 {

                 }


        }
```

But:

```
 HttpResponseMessage response = await theAuthClient.SendAsync(request);
```

gives me error:

> {System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))}
>
> "Use of networking APIs requires the ID_CAP_NETWORKING capability to
>   be defined in the application manifest."
>
> "   at MS.Internal.Modern.ClientHttpWebRequestCreator.Create(Uri
>   uri)\r\n   at System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Uri requestUri, Boolean
>   schemeOnly)\r\n   at System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Uri requestUri)\r\n 
>   at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.CreateAndPrepareWebRequest(HttpRequestMessage
>   request)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack
>   trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at
>   Merakyahoga.com.Pages.MedicalVertical.Common.MedicalGooglePlusLoginPage.d__11.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at
>   Merakyahoga.com.Pages.MedicalVertical.Common.MedicalGooglePlusLoginPage.d__b.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.b__3(Object
>   state)\r\n   at
>   System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.InvokeCore()"

I have already enabled **Internet** from **Capabilities** on **Package.appxmanifest**

Actually it goes to Continuationmanager.cs:

```
case ActivationKind.WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuation:
                var wabPage = rootFrame.Content as IWebAuthenticationContinuable;
                if (wabPage != null)
                {
                    wabPage.ContinueWebAuthentication(args as WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs);
                }
                break;
```

Then to app.xaml.cs:

```
  protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
            {
                base.OnActivated(args);

                continuationManager = new ContinuationManager();

                var continuationEventArgs = args as IContinuationActivatedEventArgs;
                if (continuationEventArgs == null)
                    return;

                var frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
                if (frame != null)
                {
                    // Call ContinuationManager to handle continuation activation
                    continuationManager.Continue(continuationEventArgs, frame);
                }
            }
```

and crashes here.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add `ID_CAP_NETWORKING` to `Properties\WMAppManifest.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Actual problem is that i was using HTTPClient from System.Net 
I now replaced it to Windows.Web HTTPClient